# Problem with python multiple sorting. Alphabetical descending order

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of tuples in which each element is like the following: `(String, Integer)`. I want to sort the list by the second element of the tuples in ascending order and if some tuple have the same Integer, I want these ones to be sorted by their first element(String) **but in descending order**.
If the first element was an Integer i would normally do: `list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], -x[0])`, but since is a String I can't pass the lambda a negative String!

PS: I can't import any library. Thanks!

Comment: Pass the integer as a negative and use the `reverse=True` kwarg to `sort()`.  This way the strings will be sorted in reverse order, and the integers will be sorted in reverse-negative (i.e. ascending) order.

Comment: Even if the first element was an integer, that would fail, because you are passing `-x[0]` as a second parameter to `sort`.

Comment: Can it be done like this? `sorted(l, key=lambda k: (k[1], tuple(-ord(c) for c in k[0])))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
list.sort(key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]), reverse=True)
```

The lambda expression will create higher values for the items you want sorted earlier. Then the `reverse` argument will sort those to the start of the list.